# "Unhandled expression type" in SQL subquery

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

I am using XrmToolBox with SQL 4 CDS to make some edits to a user in MS Dynamics.  I don't quite know where the error lies-- in the SQL expression?  In the FetchXML that it gets converted to?  Anyway, here's my expression:

```
INSERT INTO systemuser (
  firstname,
  lastname,
  internalemailaddress,
  departmentid,
  internalspecialtyid)
VALUES (
  'John',
  'Smith',
  'john.smith@example.com',
  (SELECT TOP 1 departmentid FROM department WHERE name = 'Commercial'),
  (SELECT TOP 1 internalspecialtyid FROM internal_specialties WHERE name = 'B2B Comms'));
```

When I run this, I get this message from XrmToolBox:

```
Unhandled expression type: (SELECT TOP 1 departmentid FROM department WHERE name = 'Commercial')
```

I really don't understand this.  I can select the subquery and execute it to get one response back.  I can take its results and make it a static (non-subquery) expression with no problem.  But why isn't this working?  I'm pretty new to SQL, assuming that's where the problem is, so I could easily misunderstand the subquery syntax.

Comment: How are you executing this? from CLI or using a query tool?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL 4 CDS tool attempts to provide as much a SQL implementation for CDS/Dataverse as possible but it's not perfect.  Reach out to the tool author directly by opening an issue on the the SQL 4 CDS's GitHub page: https://github.com/MarkMpn/Sql4Cds/issues